Как использовать одну сессию Telethon для нескольких скриптов?
У меня есть сессия Telethon JSON формата. Я без проблем могу ее использовать в одном скрипте, во втором если я ее попробую использовать одновременно, Telethon выдаст

database is locked

Исправить это я попытался копированием сессии, и при прямом копировании оба скрипта запустятся, но проблема заключается в том, что если я попытаюсь отключить одну из сессий client.disconnect(), то дисконнектится и вторая сессия
И для меня это является проблемой, т.к. первая сессия выполняет простую разовую работу, поэтому должна запускаться и отключаться. А вторая сессия обрабатывает входящие сообщения, т.е. подключен event handler
И после завершения работы первого скрипта, event handler просто перестает отвечать без всяких ошибок
Как мне быть? Как использовать одну сессию на несколько скриптов? Возможно я просто что-то не так копирую?
